# Remove \r\n in awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a simple awk command that converts a date from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD. However, the file I'm using has \r\n at the end of the lines, and sometimes the date is at the end of the line.

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
  {
    split($27, date, /\//)
    $27 = date[3] "/" date[1] "/" date[2]

    print $0
  }
' file.txt
```

In this case, if the date is `MM/DD/YYYY\r\n` then I end up with this in the output:

```
YYYY
/MM/DD
```

What is the best way to get around this? Keep in mind, sometimes the input is simply `\r\n` in which case the output SHOULD be `//` but instead ends up as

```
/
/
```

Comment: Why dont you use one of the replacement functions on `date[3]` to replace `\r` with `""` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that the `\r` isn't always at the end of field `$27`, the simplest approach is to remove the `\r` from the entire line.

With **GNU Awk** or **Mawk** (one of which is typically the default `awk` on Linux platforms), you can simply define your input record separator, `RS`, accordingly:

```
awk -v RS='\r\n' ...
```

Or, if you want `\r\n`-terminated *output* lines too, set the output record separator, `ORS`, to the same value:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=ORS="\r\n"; ...
```

---

**Optional reading: an aside for BSD/macOS Awk users:**

BSD/macOS `awk` doesn't support *multi-character* `RS` values (in line with the [POSIX Awk spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html): "If `RS` contains more than one character, the results are unspecified").

Therefore, a `sub` call inside the Awk script is necessary to trim the `\r` instance from the end of each input line:

```
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); ...
```

To also *output* `\r\n`-terminated lines, option `-v ORS='\r\n'` (or `ORS="\r\n"` inside the script's `BEGIN` block) will work fine, as with GNU Awk and Mawk.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: after four hours of madness by trying to `print var_1 var_2` where the var_2 was overwriting var_1, it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a system where `\n` by itself is the newline, you should remove the `\r` from the record. You could do it like:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r/,"",$NF); ...}'
```